# Unzip .gz file when line order is important

Tags: linux, compression

I am trying to unzip fastq.gz files and then analyze the sequencing data within them. However, later analysis is dependent on preservation of line (line 1 from zipped file must be line 1 in unzipped file) in  order within the unzipped files.

When I manually look at the files, it seems to me that line order is being preserved when using gunzip to unzip the fatsq.gz files (and I wouldn't expect anything else). However, downstream analysis fails because order has not been preserved from the original file. Am I missing something about the unzipping process? Thanks.

It appears that something like the following is happening.

Sequencer writes data to fastq.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
lin4
```

Then zips it into fastq.gz. I then unzip using gunzip and appear to get something like the following, where line order is disrupted:

```
line2
line1
line4
line3
```

Comment: `gzip` won't reorder your data, so something else is going wrong in your system.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but strangely enough when I gzip the files again, line order seems to be restored.

Comment: Agree with @jjlin, gzip won't reorder your data. Something else is involved. Can you please supply the zip, unzip and analysis commands which are being used?

Comment: pretty simple, just `gunzip file` and `gzip file`

Comment: It can't be the gzip/gunzip process. You say that the 'sequencer' is performing the gzipping of fastq.txt - are you sure it is not altering the content prior to gzip?

Comment: Yes I am, I can successfully analyze my sequencing files as pairs before unzipping and then again after re-zipping the files, but not when unzipping, because when unzipped, some of the lines between file 1 and 2 are out of order.

Comment: This is pretty weird. No idea why it's happening. If it was the zip utilities, the whole world would be screaming for a fix. But ... As a workaround, (if the unzipped files are ever in the right order) couldn't you just add a line number prefix to each line before (re)compressing the file and then sort it after expanding the file? Are random lines being reordered or is there some pattern to to it? Can you take the original file to another computer or operating system and see what happens?